# MySQL Query insert a row if it doesn't exist

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that's called People and each row has a name structure, and other rows like age and such...
Anyways, I want to check if the row that has a specific name is already exists to insert a new one or not to.
This is what I went with so far:

```
$name = $_GET["name"];
$age = $_GET["age"];
$location = $_GET["location"];

$query = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM people WHERE name='" . $name . "'");
$exist = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if ($exist > 0) {
    //exist
    $connection->query("INSERT INTO people (name,age,location) VALUES ($name, $age, $location)");
} else {
    //doesn't exist
}
```

But it ain't working, is it because INSERT shouldn't be executed like that? I really don't know, anyways thanks in advance.
**EDIT:**
After searching I just got the following not working:

```
$prepare = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM people WHERE name = ?");
$prepare->bind_param("s", $name);
$prepare->execute();
$result = $prepare->get_result();
$numRows = $result->num_rows;
    if ($numRows <= 0) {
      $insert = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO people (name, age, location) VALUES (?,?,?)");
      $insert->bind_param("sis", $name, $age, $loc);
      $insert->execute();
      echo "true," . $title;
} else {
  echo "false," . $title;
}
```

But it gives me this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in C********* on line 19
```

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). What do you mean by "ain't working"? Where is your  error checking? You *assume* that all of your queries will work.

Comment: if you want to insert if the name row exist then `if ($exist > 0) {`

Comment: Use INSERT IGNORE statements and create unique index on the column you want to be unique.

Comment: @JayBlanchard  I just thought of this one: https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: sorry for being such a newbie, I'm really sorry guys your answers will help me allot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$insert` is `false` because an error occurred in the given prepare statement.
You might have a typo, so to verify that you can just check:

```
if (!$insert) {
    echo $connection->error;
}
```

Comment: it gives `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-name, age, loc) VALUES (?,?,?)' at line 1`

Comment: No problem, printing errors can solve almost all the problems ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should use prepared statements to avoid SQL-injections (as mentioned by Jay Blanchard). You should look into [Sanitize Filters](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php) to filter your`$_POST` variables.

If you wish to have unique names in your database, you can use the `unique` key in the database, or by coding:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM people WHERE name='$name'");
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // If results, the name exists
    echo "Someone with the name $name are already in our database!";
} else {
    // Else we insert it!
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO people (name,age,location) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param('sis', $name, $age, $location);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

You're mixing object-oriented syntaxes and Procedural syntaxes, I'm assuming you're using object oritented (as that's what you had the most of).

Answer (score -1):

if you try to insert a new record or update an insert record, spend some time and read / understand the syntac mysql provides .. you can read it here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: why the down-vote? can the down-voter explain? It seems like a valid answer to me.

Comment: It is likely because you posted a link instead of explaining how the information in the link might help the OP.